# Handling nil Exceptions in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2

i am new to IOS and swift 2. i know in java that performing a try catch on a block will catch the stated exceptions but now in swift i have a function that may have a nil value. so i did this:

```
do
{
  try  //the function that may be nil
}
catch let error1 as NSError
{
  print (error1)
}
```

but on the try i am getting an alert saying No calls to throwing functions occur within try expression. Also i ran the app and intentionally had the variable as nil and the app crashed without handling the exception though i had try..

so how can i catch nil exceptions

i know i can put `if (value != nil)` but i want to know if this can be handeled in another way

thank you

Comment: Never force unwrapping an optional if it may be nil. No way to catch such error, you just should not do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two or more ways to handle optional nil errors.

First of all "optional unwrapping" is like "Unchecked exception in java" so, you can not handle like normal try-catch block, if you want then you should use "**throws** machanism like you use for unchecked exceptions.

2nd in the context of ios swift 2.0 you can use

```
enum MyError: ErrorType {
  case UserError
  case NetworkError
  case DiscoverydError
}
func doStuff() throws -> String {
   print("Do stuff 1")
   print("Do stuff 2")
   throw MyError.NetworkError //using "throw"
   return "Some return value"
}
do {
   try doStuff()
   print("Success")
} catch {
   print("An error occurred.")
}
```

1)

```
 if let value = optionalVariable{
 // use value here instead of optionalVariable so, you no need to unwrap 
 }
```

2)use guard statemnts

```
 guard let value = optionalVariable else {

      return 
 }
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. Is there a way better than the other?

Comment: what are you looking for?? these three ways are present in ios to handle nil. And they are very enough. 
where are you confuse??